# BackboneJS return PHP array to [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object, backbone.js

I'm new to BackboneJS and Jquery so I have a problem when trying to return JSON data from php array.

this is my code:
Model:

```
var NoteModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize:function(){
    console.log('Model initialize');
        },
    url : '../www/api/controller.php'
});
```

View:

```
var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#result',
    // /var note = new NoteModel();
    //template : _.template($("#result-view-template").html()),
    initialize:function(){
        console.log('View initialize');
    },
    render :function(){
         //var note = new NoteModel();
         var note = new NoteModel();
         var template = _.template($("#result-view-template").html(),{result : note});
         this.$el.html(template); 
         return this; 
    }
});
```

Route:

```
Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;


var NoteRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes : {
        "result" : "displayMessage"

    },
    displayMessage : function(){
        var notemodel = new NoteModel();
        var noteview  = new NoteView();
        notemodel.fetch({
            success: function(){
                  noteview.render();
                }
            })
        }    
    });



var router = new NoteRouter();


Backbone.history.start();
```

PHP Api:

```
<?php 

$datas = array(
    'result '=> 'PHP array data'
    );

$data = json_encode($datas);

echo $data;


?>
```

Html view :

```
<div id="result"></div>
        <script type="text/template" id="result-view-template">
        <%= result %>
             <p>result should be here</p>
        </script>
```

it should return the php array data on the #result div but it's not, instead of returned [object Object] on the #result  div.

Comment: Have you seen in your Network panel (in Firebug or webtools) what actually arrives to your browser instead of <%= result %> ??

Comment: I do console.log(noteview) and it return this
r {cid: "view2", $el: n.fn.init[1], el: div#result, constructor: function, initialize: function…}

Answer (score 0):

You try parse the Model itself into the template, but you actually want to parse the result of the fetch method of the Model.
Either you fetch the model object (returned from the server) from within the render function of the note_View object, or you instantiate the model in the router and pass it as 'options' parameter to the initializer function of the note_View.

You can do something like:

Router:

```
    var notemodel = new NoteModel();
    notemodel.fetch({
        success: function(returned_model){
            var noteview  = new NoteView({model : returned_model});
            }
        })
    }
```

View:

```
var NoteView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#result',
    initialize:function(options){
        this.model = options.model; 
        this.render(); 
    },
    render :function(){
         var template = _.template($("#result-view-template").html(),{result : this.model});
         this.$el.html(template); 
         return this; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing whole object into the template. Don't put any object like this. If you want to access attributes, specify it like model.attribute.